# Get Index of Column Name to Map with DataTable C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop, excel-interop

I want to import an excel data in database. I have an excel which gets updated by team every month and they add new column with name "Jan data format" (current month name + "data format"). which gets added after the last month column.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SOURCE");
            dt.Columns.Add("DUMMY CODE");
            dt.Columns.Add("CUSTOMER CODE");
            dt.Columns.Add("STK_CODE");

            DataRow row;

            while (((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)wks.Cells[rowIndex, 1]).Value2 != null)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row[0] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)wks.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex]).Value2);
                row[1] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)wks.Cells[rowIndex, 2]).Value2);
                row[2] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)wks.Cells[rowIndex, 3]).Value2);
                row[3] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)wks.Cells[rowIndex, 4]).Value2);
                index++;

                rowIndex = 2 + index;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Here `row[1] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)wks.Cells[rowIndex, 2]).Value2);` i'm using column index. 
How to use Column Name in place of column index?

Comment: `row["SOURCE"]` etc.? Or are you referring to the `Excel.Range`?

Comment: @Jimi row["SOURCE"] etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only non-index identifier a column has in Excel is the letter one sees at the top of the column: `A`, `B`, etc. This cannot be changed.

Any text typed in a cell above other cells, which *looks like* a column header/name is just text, as far as Excel is concerned.

> I'm using column index. How to use Column Name in place of column index?

So there is no such thing as a "Column Name", therefore there's no way to use string information to identify a column.

It would be necessary to loop all the cells in a row, testing their value, to identify a column that has a particular string as the column heading. Something like

```
string headerName ="two";
Excel.Worksheet sh = (Excel.Worksheet) excelApp.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range headerRow = (Excel.Range) sh.UsedRange.Rows[1];
Excel.Range col = null;

foreach(Excel.Range cel in headerRow.Cells)
{
    if (cel.Text.ToString().Equals(headerName))
    {
        col = sh.Range[cel.Address, cel.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown]];
        break;
    }
}

foreach(Excel.Range cellInCol in col)
{
    Debug.Print(cellInCol.Value2.ToString());
}
```